# I'm having an error using default props in ReactJS. It says "Typo in static class property declaration react/no-typos"

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[Typo in static class property declaration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xFFbG.png)

CODE:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class Learnreactdeafult extends React.Component
{
  render(){
    return <h1>Hi {this.props.topic} {this.props.message} </h1>
  }
}
Learnreactdeafult.defaultprops={topic:"Ravenswag",message:"welcome"}
ReactDOM.render(<Learnreactdeafult topic="Raven"/>,document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: `Learnreactdeafult.defaultprops` needs to be `Learnreactdeafult.defaultProps`, with a capital P

Comment: That's a horrible error message. It should state the wrong and right property names.